# WPF vb.net anonymous client server relationship

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, sockets, client-server

Please bare in mind that I do not know if this is possible. The answer my be right in my face, but I do not know.

I want to create a client/server relationship that the client program connects to a server program with out knowing the server program IP?

If the Server program echo's a message through out the network, and the client listening to the echo, would this work?

SO how would a client program connect to a server program with out knowing its IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broadcast udp.  They both have to be on the same LAN.  That's how games often find local servers when browsing for them -- but for "internet" games, you always have to have the IP address (or corresponding DNS name)

See here for an example: [Sending UDP broadcast, receiving multiple messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832770/sending-udp-broadcast-receiving-multiple-messages)

Comment: Thanks. Yes they are on the same LAN. I will try this and mark if it works!